# Cheerio - Unable to obtain children of element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

This is the output when printing my `${element}`:
[image]

I wish to obtain the data of the first child of my `${element}` that has a type: `"text"` and data `valid duration (hours:minutes:seconds)`. In my case I want to obtain `"5:01"`.

However, when trying to obtain all the children using `${element}.children()` I get the following:
[image]

Basically there is no `data` and no `type` which I can check/obtain. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you write down the relevant part of the HTML you are trying to parse and your Javascript code to parse it? If we are able to reproduce and debug it, it will be easier for everyone.

Comment: can you check. my solution if it works?

Answer (score 2):

From the log image I can see children property is an array not a function.

**Following Code** should get you the desired data.

```
element.children.find(child => child.type == 'text').data;
```

Comment: @pguardiario regular array has `find` method

Comment: I had a similar data structure to OP and this solved it 

Answer (score 1):

`${element}.children().first().data()`

Comment: Try to add a selector `${element}.children('type="text"').first().data()`

Comment: It still outputs undefined for me. The problem is that when printing `$(element).children()`, `data` and `type` are missing as you can see in the picture above.

Comment: Children() itself wouldn't show you the element. Indeed it gives back an array of the child elements. So to make sure the data are there or not try to print `children()[0]`